# Excel VBA Run-time error '424': Object Required when trying to Save and Close a Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am doing a loop in order to copy all the headers from all of the files from a folder. When i try to close the file i got an error. This happends inside the with statement. Basicaly i open the file from my Desktop, copy the headers and i can't close the file as i got that error **Object Required**

Please let me know if you need more details. Thank you in advance!

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()
Dim wb, y, export As Workbook
Dim myPath, CopyPath, CopyFile As String
Dim myFile  As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
Dim LR      As Long
Dim rgCut   As Excel.Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With FldrPicker
    .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
myPath = myPath
If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
myExtension = "*.xls*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
    'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
    DoEvents
    Set rgCut = wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").EntireRow
    Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\icohen\Desktop\exceltest.xlsx")
    Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\icohen\Desktop\exceltest.xlsx").Activate
    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    With y
        Sheets(1).Cells.Select
        If LR = 0 Then
            rgCut.Copy Destination:=Selection.Range("A1")

        Else
            rgCut.Copy Destination:=Selection.Range("A" & LR)
            .Save            ' Here i receive the error
            .Close           ' Here i receive the error

        End If

    End With

    'Save and Close Workbook
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

    'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
    DoEvents

    'Get next file name
    myFile = Dir
Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying y.save and y.close?   With the previous statement doing a named range cut and paste in selection, it might be confusing the system, despite the With statement.

Comment: You're opening the same workbook twice: you only need `y.Activate` there.

Comment: Thank you Cyril! i did like this just because i had other errors :( i found the way of copying to be suitable like this.

Comment: @Tim Williams you rock! lol! stupid mistake! is a bit late for me!

Comment: do not assume that Sheets(1) will always be the same worksheet. you should really refer to it by name

Comment: get rid of `Sheets(1).Cells.Select` ... use `rgCut.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A1")`

Comment: thank you jstola! i have to paste the data into a file that has different last row all the time, this is why i used <code> Sheets(1).Cells.Select </code>

Comment: @jsotola `Sheets("some name")` shouldn't be assumed to exist either; users can (and do!) easily rename a worksheet. Also, prefer the `Worksheets` collection; the `Sheets` collection can contain charts, which don't quite play nicely with most of the code that deals with `Worksheet` objects.

Comment: @Mat'sMug, you are absolutely correct. but if someone renames the worksheet then the code will fail, instead of trampling all over sheets(1)

Comment: paste `Sheets(1).Cells.Select` into the _Immediate window_ and press enter. ... do this while you can see sheets(1) .... i think that you will find that the code does something other then what you think it does

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider your in-line multiple declaration habit (is it?), as in:

```
Dim wb, y, export As Workbook
```

In this list of variables, "Export" is a Workbook, but "wb" and "y" are just Variants. If you wanted all three of them to be declared as workbooks you need to spell it out, variable by variable; that's how VBA works :)

```
Dim wb As Workbook, y As Workbook, export As Workbook
```

It does save some room doing it in-line... but I always do each declaration in it's own line of code (Dim...)--a matter of choice.

Other than that, it's  not "Sheets" but ".Sheets"

```
With y
    .Sheets(1).Cells.Select
```

Although why you do it I do not know...
The following should do just fine:

```
y.Sheets(1).Select
Rows("1:1").Copy
y.Sheets(2).Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: you should go one more step with this. and finish  `y.Sheets(1).Rows("1:1").Copy`  `y.Sheets(2).Range("A1").Paste`

Comment: It does seem like a very logical evolution of the approach but it is not possible since Range object **does not have a Paste method** in VBA. However, there is a **PasteSpecial** method and it will work indeed. John Cohen had a problem to resolve not a desire to find the most optimal or concise solution. As an explanation, spelling it out was a better approach, I thought. Thank you for your comment nonetheless!